# migrating from postgresql 9.3 to 9.4, postgis

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgis, archlinux

I upgraded from postgresql 9.3 to 9.4 and now I want to migrate my data.

So this is what I tried to do. First I ran the old postgresql like so

```
/opt/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data/ start
```

Then, I tried to dump the old database to a file:

```
/opt/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_dumpall >> old_backup.sql
```

And it told me:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
```

So okay, I tried to find the postgis-2.1 files and copy them to the `libdir`

```
find / -name "*postgis-2.1*"
/usr/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.1.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so
/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1 <-----
```

Okay, now what's the `libdir`?

```
/opt/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config --pkglibdir
/opt/pgsql-9.3/lib
```

So I made a symbolic link in `/opt/pgsql-9.3/lib` to `here /usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1`:

```
 pwd
/opt/pgsql-9.3/lib
ls -l postgis-2.1
postgis-2.1 -> /usr/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1
```

But still I get the error: query failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory

I'm kind of out of ideas. Maybe someone can help me?

I'm usnig arch linux

P.S

Postgis is installed:

```
pacman -S postgis
warning: postgis-2.1.5-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
```

And here are the binaries:

```
find / -name "*postgis-2.1*"
/usr/lib/postgresql/rtpostgis-2.1.so   <---- binary
/usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so     <----- binary
/opt/pgsql-9.3/lib/postgis-2.1         <----- that's the symlink from earlier
/usr/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1
```

Comment: You tried pg_dump _after_ the upgrade?

Comment: And the upgrade was performed usong `pg_upgrade` ? BTW: did you run ldconfig, after your juggling act with the symlinked shared libraries?

Comment: no. I upgraded using pacman -Syu. I just did a normal upgrade. 
I didn't run ldconfig. I don't know what it is. I'll check that out right now.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for the ldconfig hint. I read about it, but I;m not sure how to use it in this case and I;m afraid to experiment. Can you please tell me how should I run it in these particular circumstances?

Comment: [I dont know pacman] Normally: (as root) `ldconfig` , or `ldconfig -v` for more verbosity. Your .so files should show up in the output. (when not: there is something wrong with your configuration files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbolic link is pointing to the "share" files, used for `CREATE EXTENSION` and family. What you need is to point the `.so` files inside the directory returned by `pg_config --pkglibdir`:

```
$ rm /opt/pgsql-9.3/lib/postgis-2.1 # it is a wrong link, so undo it
$ ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/postgis-2.1.so /opt/pgsql-9.3/lib/
```

Now the PostGIS `.so` file will be in `"$libdir"` and you'll be able to perform `pg_dumpall`.

Of course keeping it that way does not strike me as sane setup, but as your upgrading I'm assuming this is just an intermediate state and you'll remove PostgreSQL 9.3 entirely after that. You must also verify if PostGIS is linked with 9.3 libraries, if not you might have some problems.

Answer (score 9):

I have similar problem, but solve it a bit differently:

```
dbname=#\dx

  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                             Description
---------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis | 2.1.5   | postgis    | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions


dbname=#ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '2.2.0';
dbname=#\dx

  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                             Description
---------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis | 2.2.0   | postgis    | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
```

Comment: Just upgraded to PostGIS 2.2.0 from 2.1.7 on OS X (Homebrew), and this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is the official way of upgrading the postgis extension already installed in a database, so it should be preferable to other answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution with Docker was:

```
docker exec -i $(docker-compose ps -q postgis) ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/postgis-2.3.so /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/lib/postgis-2.1.so
```